# Calling an object in a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code I'm working on:

```
 function price ([arg1,arg2]) {
    let city1 = {coffee:0.5, water:0.8, beer:1.2, sweets:1.45, peanuts:1.6};
    let city2 = {coffee:0.4, water:0.9, beer:1.4, sweets:1.25, peanuts:1.8};
    console.log (arg1[arg2]);
}

price (["city1","water"])
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is, have the price of a particular product be listed when you call the function with the city name and the product.

From what I can see, it's because "city1" gets input as a string, which is why I get no results when calling the function. Any ideas how I can convert the arg1 input from string to an object?

I looked into using window and eval, but I wasn't able to find a way to properly use them in this one. I know it's a dumb question, and that I'm probably missing something obvious, but I pretty much tried everything I can think of.

Comment: what you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: Have the console log 0.8 in this case when the  function is called with the object name city1 and the property "water". It's for a homework in a programming basics course (they want us to use if/else if, but I was thinking there could be an alternate way to do thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rethink how you're using the objects. By using the bracket notation rather than the dot notation for accessing object properties you are able to pass in a string, which is helpful for getting values not known beforehand. Below is an example but do note you also should check if the property actually exists as well.

Also worth mentioning is that you shouldn't pass your argument in as an array like that. Either pass them in directly or use an object.

```js
function price (city, item) {
    let cities = {
      city1 : {coffee:0.5, water:0.8, beer:1.2, sweets:1.45, peanuts:1.6},
      city2 : {coffee:0.4, water:0.9, beer:1.4, sweets:1.25, peanuts:1.8}
    }
   let res = cities[city][item]
   console.log(res)
   return res;
}

price ("city1", "water")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the cities as key for an object and access it via a key, as well as the key for the product.

```js
function price(city, product) {
    return (data[city] || {})[product];
}

var data = { city1: { coffee: 0.5, water: 0.8, beer: 1.2, sweets: 1.45, peanuts: 1.6 }, city2: { coffee: 0.4, water: 0.9, beer: 1.4, sweets: 1.25, peanuts: 1.8 } };

console.log(price("city1", "water"));
console.log(price("foo", "bar"));
```

Comment: +1 because It's better to define the data array outside the function so that it's not recreated each time. This also has a clever way of checking if the property exists.